# Binding a simple business class to a WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wrappanel

I did quite a bit of WPF a couple of years ago but seem to have forgotten everything.

Suppose I have a simple business class, say a TFS workitem.

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public WorkItem(string name, DateTime date)
    {
        Name = name;
        Date = date;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a list of WorkItems, perhaps something like this.

```
class WiList : ObservableCollection<WorkItem>
{
    public WiList () : base()
    {
        Add(new WorkItem("1", DateTime.Now));
        Add(new WorkItem("2", DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Then I have a UserControl that represents a WorkItem, something like this.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="WrapPanelItemsControlTest.WorkItemControl"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Height="40">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Name"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Date"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The main window contains a WrapPanel to hold the UserControls. My question is, how do I create a WrapPanel that binds to the WiList and displays the WorkItems? I remember doing something like this before, but for the death of me I can't remember how (probably something from Bea Costa's blog). Of course I can't find my old test code anywhere and seem to be expectionally bad at googling for examples.

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use `ItemsControl` for this. `WrapPanel` can be used as layout panel for the elements of the collection. And if you only need the `UserControl` to show properties of one object, then the better choice would be to use a `DataTemplate`. Here's some XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:WorkItem}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <ItemsControl
        x:Name="itemsList"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorkItemTemplate}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

And in code-behind bind the `ItemsControl` to the collection:

```
itemsList.ItemsSource = new WIList(); // or wherever the collection comes from
```

P.S. Initializing `ItemsSource` and generally accessing controls from code-behind to bind them to data is not a good practice. You would need a ViewModel (Presenter) class as the DataContext of your window. If you consider staying for some time with WPF my advice is - try to use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

P.P.S. Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `WorkItem` if you need WPF to keep up with changes of properties' values.

Comment: Initializing ItemsSource _from code-behind_ is not a good practice. You probably meant that, but it may not be clear from the P.S.

+1 =)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to bind an instance of your WiList class to a ItemsControl's ItemsSource and then apply a DataTemplate for your WorkItem.

There's a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575976/binding-observablecollection-items-to-usercontrol-in-wrappanel).

You can find out more about the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx).